# Transfer "blobs" between grpc client - server

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have two services that communicate with each other using gRPC.
Is it possible to transfer JObject or some "blob" object like that via gRPC?
This is in my case neseccary because the service is in this specific case not interesseted in the content of the Jobject and just saves the object into a mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in two different ways:

1. If you're using gRPC under the default marshaller implementation (i.e. protocol buffers, "protobuf"), then you can use the `bytes` type for a field to transmit a blob (or `string` for a clob)
2. If you want to get more exotic, gRPC doesn't *actually* mandate the marshaller, so you can swap it out for *whatever you want*, but this requires writing your own code to register the services and provide the marshaller - not a trivial topic, depending on the implementation / framework that you're using (I can provide examples of doing this in .NET with protobuf-net.Grpc, but in other frameworks you'd need to figure it out yourself)

Comment: thank you very much!! How about transfering large zips. How would you transer those?

Comment: @moinster - streaming

Comment: I won't recomment using String for this purpose, better use bytes and use Codec compression with it. This would be much efficient I think.